# Should I add files that are part of the Ruby Standard Library to the `Gemfile`?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, heroku, openssl, bundler

I need to do `require 'openssl'` in my code. Otherwise, I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Object::OpenSSL`. But, when I do `gem list`, I don't see `openssl`. I'm deploying a Sinatra app to Heroku stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2. Should I add `openssl` to the `Gemfile`? I don't think so because I think [`openssl` is part of the Ruby Standard Library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/index.html). Also, what about [`base64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/base64/rdoc/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to include gems in the Gemfile that are in the Ruby Standard Library *for the versions of Ruby you support*.

You can have your program auto-require all gems in Gemfile. Rails does this. Otherwise, just `require 'gem_name'` in the files that require it.

Answer (score -1):

It's very likely that you have compiled ruby without openssl support. If you are using RVM, you can try [this](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/)

Comment: No, everything works fine. I'm just wondering if I should also add `openssl` and `base64` to the gem file.