# Installing jQuery on Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following this rails cast on ajax pagination with rails. http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

I'm getting the following error when i try to install jquery

```
rails g jquery:install
'connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

The tutorial suggests adding this to the applicaiton.rb file but it gives the following error.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

rails g jquery:install
`<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Object::OpenSSL (NameError)
```

I'm running Ruby version

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
```

and Rails version

```
Rails 3.0.5
```

Any have experience with this error?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778071/do-i-need-to-add-openssl-to-gemfile  try doing what is suggested on that post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the error you're getting is... but if you want to install jquery for rails you just need to get and download the newest version of jquery from jquery.com, and then go here:  https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs  which is the rails.js file for jquery.  Then delete any prototype.js and other js files except application.js that the app first came installed with.

As long as you have jquery.js and rails.js and are including them in your application layout file, all of the railsisms will work such as `:remote => true`, `:disable_with => "My Message"`, and `:confirm => "Are you sure about that?"`, in addition to whatever that railscast talks about.